# Include variance change at point in ARIMA model estimation in R

Tags: time-series, arima, residuals, heteroscedasticity

I have a series which I am trying to model through ARIMA approach. However, when checking the residuals, there appears to be a change in variance at a specific point. This is, given the residuals $e_t$, then
$$
\text{Var}(e_t) = \begin{cases}
\sigma_1^2 \quad\text{if } t<t_0 \\
\sigma_2^2 \quad\text{if } t\geq t_0
\end{cases}
$$
where $t_0$ is a given known change point. The rest of the ARIMA model is the same

Is there a way to fit this type of model? And is there an interface in R to fit such kinds of models? Or would it be appropriate to just fit two different models, one before $t_0$ and one after.